# input type tag missing in browser when tested through wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I've started coding html in wordpress. I have a html code with label tag and an input tag of type "text". The input field is not getting displayed in browser. The same code works fine in eclipse. What might be the problem. When I save the post as draft the  tag disappears. Not able to solve the issue. Kindly help me in this regard.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Hello testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> <label> Name:</label> <input type="text"> </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Above image is the code run through eclipse

[image]

Above one is the image run through wordpress preview

Comment: What do mean by "started html coding in wordpress"? Are you adding the html code in the content editor of the post?

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm building a html page with to accept name and age and a submit button.

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

when writing html in the Wordpress editor, you can only use tags that are allowed by Wordpress. Dont think the input tag is one if them.
Look at this:
https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#html-tags

Comment: Ive seen few other wordpress blog page source where input tag is being used. Im not finding any solutions. How to add a textbox if input is not allowed?

Comment: If you’re not into php, then you can use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The "input" tag is not supported by WordPress editor.